# weight painting one side of my model affects the other side in a strange way

Tags: weight-painting

When I'm weight painting at the right side, it acts strange on the left side. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: It seems like you're mirroring the weight paint? Please explain your setup in more detail, as this leaves to speculation

Answer (score 1):

You are using x-mirror option:

[image]

But, if you name bones correctly,  x-mirror will work for you. You need to name pairs of bone with postfixes "`.R`" and "`.L`" like "`arm.L`" and "`arm.R`". If you do so, when you will paint weight group "`arm.L`", "`arm.R`" will be symmetrical to "`arm.L`"

Also, learn about [rigify](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYiAd_08-0k)